Apex Create Lookup Field w Filters - Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from VALUE_TRUE value true or request may be missing a required field
I am attempting to create a Lookup field with Filter Criteria using the Tooling API.
Http http = new Http();
            
// Instantiate a new HTTP request
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v60.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/');

req.setMethod('POST');

// Content-Type  header is set to let the service know that the sent data is in JSON format
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

String newMeta = '{"Metadata" : { "type" : "Lookup", "deleteConstraint": "SetNull", "description" : "The Institutional Unit associated with this record.", "inlineHelpText" : "The Institutional Unit associated with this record.","label" : "Institutional Unit","required" : false, "lookupFilter" : { "active" : true, "filterItems" : [{"value" : "Institutional Unit","operation" : "equals","field" : "Account.RecordType.Name","valueField" : null}], "isOptional" : true},"relationshipLabel" : "Person Education","relationshipName" : "PersonEducation","referenceTo" : "Account"}, "FullName" : "personeducation.InstitutionalUnit__c"}';
req.setBody(newMeta);
req.setTimeout(20000);

System.debug(newMeta);

try{
    HttpResponse res2 =  http.send(req);
    System.debug(res2.toString());
    System.debug(res2.getBody());
} catch (Exception e){
    System.debug('Exception');
    System.debug(e);
}         

When running this code, I receive the following error:
[{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from VALUE_TRUE value true or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:296]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
I have isolated the issue to the "lookupFilter" section - if you remove that part, the field is created successfully.
I used the Salesforce Documentation for CustomField, LookupFilter, and FilterItem as my reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm
Any ideas of what might be missing or wrong? Thank you in advance.
Edit for context:
I have created the field in the Admin UI prior, copied its metadata, deleted the field, and used it in this script.
String newMeta = '{"FullName":"personeducation.InstitutionalUnit__c","Metadata":{"businessOwnerGroup":null,"businessOwnerUser":null,"businessStatus":null,"caseSensitive":null,"complianceGroup":null,"customDataType":null,"defaultValue":null,"deleteConstraint":"SetNull","deprecated":null,"description":"The Institutional Unit associated with this record.","displayFormat":null,"displayLocationInDecimal":null,"elementType":null,"encryptionScheme":null,"escapeMarkup":null,"externalDeveloperName":null,"externalId":false,"formula":null,"formulaTreatBlanksAs":null,"inlineHelpText":"The Institutional Unit associated with this record.","isAIPredictionField":null,"isConvertLeadDisabled":null,"isFilteringDisabled":null,"isNameField":null,"isSortingDisabled":null,"label":"Institutional Unit","length":null,"lookupFilter":{"booleanFilter":null,"filterItems":[{"field":"Account.RecordType.Name","operation":"equals","value":"Institutional Unit","valueField":null}],"active":true,"description":null,"errorMessage":null,"infoMessage":null,"isOptional":false}}}';

The issue still points to filterCriteria > active, saying it cannot deserialize the boolean value.

Step 1: create a lookup field with filter criteria via admin UI. Step 2: download the metadata for said field. Step 3: fix your code and post the answer as to what you did wrong.

Hey thanks for reply, I should've mentioned in the post that these were the initial troubleshooting steps taken. Doing this method again and using the existing metadata to build the new field, it still points to lookupFilter > active as the issue. Same error as before with not being able to deserialize its boolean value despite the metadata being directly copied from existing sources.

Try https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
